# Resize UILabel based on content inside UITableViewCell iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am using a `UITableViewCell` which contains few `ImageView` and `Labels`. I have given the image of how the cell looks for your reference. I need the Content label to expand and contract based on the text within it, without disturbing any other views inside the cell. I am new to `AutoLayouts` and I am facing issues with it. Please help.

[image: The layout of the UITableViewCell]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `NSLayoutConstraint` in the storyboard and then hook it up to a property in your code.  Here is an example of one I did with width, but you can do the same with height.

[image]

The referencing outlet in the .h file is:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintAuctionHouseNameWidth;
```

Then in the .m Controller file I figure out the size of the new label and set the constraint to that as shown below.

You then need to figure out the size of the text in your label, which is going to determine the size of the label to show it in.  Here is how I do it: (`auctionHouseObject.name` is the text that goes into the label)

```
//calculate width of label
CGRect r = [auctionHouseObject.name boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(350, 0)
                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Bold" size:15]}
                context:nil];
```

Then I set the width programmatically.  (`auctionHouseNameLabelMaxWidth` is different depending on the screen width of the phone)

```
    if(r.size.width < auctionHouseNameLabelMaxWidth){
        cell.constraintAuctionHouseNameWidth.constant = r.size.width + 2;
    }
    else{
        cell.constraintAuctionHouseNameWidth.constant = auctionHouseNameLabelMaxWidth;
    }
```

Set the other constraints in the storyboard and Autolayout should take care of the rest.

Comment: what is r.size.width ?

Comment: r is a `CGRect` that is the size of the text I am putting in the `UILabel`.  I create the `CGRect` among other things to determine the length of the label.  So that piece of the code says: if the width of the text is less than the maximum label width, the width constraint should be the width (length) of the text (plus 2), otherwise just make it the max width of the label.  For your code you would set the `constraint.constant` to the height that you wanted your "Content label" to be.  (I am assuming it is the height that you want to vary, but it works the same for the width also)

Comment: Based on the comment _I need the Content label to expand and contract based on the text within it_ I assumed that you know the size of "Content label".  That is what you will set your constraint to.  That is what I did with mine, it just happened to be stored in `r.size.width`

Comment: Oh k. Sorry i dont get what you so. Its totally messed up.

Comment: Do you know the height of "Content label"?

Comment: No its dynamic, it will change based on the text

Comment: Please see the updated answer where I added the information on how to determine the size of the text that is given dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81828/discussion-between-shaik-md-ashiq-and-dstudeba).